# Kohana admin system

Tags: system, kohana, admin, store

Does anybody have any idea if there exists a demo of a Kohana admin system? (i am thinking at one admin system like Django has one). I am building an online store, and i need a quick way to manage the products inside it. Is there any chance for me to be able to use the Kohana admin system in order to perform this task?

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

i don't know any kohana admin.
the kohana auth will help you to create a security log-in but kohana don't have any pre-builded admin or scaffold.
The cause of kohana don't have any scaffold system or admin is because you will spend more time changing or adapting the admin/scaffold to your needs than do it from zero.
Kohana give you very very impressive tools to build and validate the forms.
If you read the docs carefully and you understand the docs you can program your own admin in less than half an our i guarantee you

Answer (score 2):

A few months ago I was looking for something exactly what you are asking about. I was unable to find a finished product but I found many pieces. I have since been glueing them together as I see fit into the night. The project is quite a buggy mess right now but it works for my purposes. Once I get it in better shape I planned on posting it to my website or maybe github if I ever figure it out that is...

Lately however my job has gotten a bit stricter in regards to coming in early... so I can't code away into the night like I used to. Also, the last component: jQuery mobile UI is still in Alpha 3 so I'm in no major rush either...

My main questions are...

1. The following are the components it utilizes, will those work with your project?
2. If 1 == true... and this is for a potential project when would you need/like this module by?

Jelly -->
https://github.com/jonathangeiger/kohana-jelly

Formo -->
https://github.com/bmidget/kohana-formo

Formo-Jelly -->
https://github.com/bmidget/kohana-formo-jelly

Jelly-Auth -->
https://github.com/raeldc/jelly-auth

Jelly-Auth-Demo -->
https://github.com/rob/jelly-auth-demo

A neat admin template style -->
http://mathew-davies.co.uk/2010/03/13/free-admin-template.html

A x12 Grid from -->
http://960.gs/

jQuery Mobile UI Elements -->
http://jquerymobile.com/

Posted as answer instead of a message, just in case others are interested... Gauging the amount of interest will likely determine the amount of evening time sacrificed.

Comment: No problem... are you interested in the said Admin system? Or will these components not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Kohana does not have a magical admin system like Django.